# Default timeout for webservice soap requests?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

Could someone tell me what the default timeout for soap webservice calls is?

```
  ((BindingProvider) Port).getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
            30);
    ((BindingProvider) Port).getRequestContext().put(
            BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
            30);
```

I can set this manually of course, but what is default if I omit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just print out the value of this using the CONNECT_TIMEOUT property?

> System.getProperty(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT)

Comment: In my program, this returns null. What is the timeout value used when this property is null?